# Livedata onChanged getting called multiple times

Tags: android, observer-pattern, android-room, android-livedata

I have the following query which simply return list of items from the given ids, and I'm observing the returned list.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Model WHERE modelId IN (:ids)")
LiveData<List<Model>> getModels(List<String> ids);
```

My problem is that I'm dynamically sending the ids to be observed on, the `onChanged` getting called X amount of calling the method itself with all the previous values.

Here is how I'm observing on the list.

```
 @Override
public void setModels(List<String> ids) {
     getDatabase().modelsDao().getModels(ids).observe(this, models -> {
            if (models != null) {
                setFilterList(models);
            }
        });
  }
```

Example:

`setModels(list(2 items));`

First time result:

`onChanged((list(2 items));`

---

`setModels((list(7 items));`

Second time result:

```
onChanged((list(2 items))
onChanged((list(7 items))
```

Also Tried to `removeObserver` but it didn't help

Comment: `LiveData#removeObserver()` works just fine - you just passed wrong observer, but you could also try ``LiveData#removeObservers()`` if you have problems with passing valid observer

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately  `removeObservers()` didn't help.

Comment: @pskink Ill search about them.

Comment: @pskink can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861779/observer-calling-twice-android

Comment: Did you figure this out?